# How can you boil milk without causing it to foam and overflow?

Tags: boiling-point

I have looked at this [Why does milk overflow...](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32529/why-does-milk-overflow-when-boiled/37334#37334)

But I've not found a solution to prevent the milk overflowing.

I remember reading (cannot recall the source) that in industries where milk is boiled a that some sort of silicone treatment on the boiler prevents the milk from overflowing. Can someone elaborate on this?

What other methods can be used to prevent milk from overflowing when boiled?
This is a huge problem for housewives in India, who have to boil milk everyday.

[Unlike in the US, in India you can never be sure that the milk you buy is uncontaminated or even pasteurized. Also, milk is boiled to sterilize it, rather than pasteurized, this probably kills off all pathogens. Boiling it beyond sterilizing, boils off some smelly volatile substances that makes better yogurt]

Comment: A double boiler would help, but that would take longer and use more fuel. But without the bubbling due to the direct heat you're less likely to drive off the "volatile substances" to which you refer.

Comment: The classic "rest a cooking spoon on the surface" method seems to keep liquids from boiling over.

Also non-toxic, porous stones at the bottom of the pot ("boiling stones") prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this:
[Wikipedia - Milk Watcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_watcher)

> The milk watcher was invented by Vincent Hartley in 1938... ...A milk
>   watcher disrupts this process by collecting small bubbles of steam
>   into one large bubble and releasing it in a manner which may puncture
>   the surface film. The device also rattles when boiling occurs,
>   alerting the cook who may then lower the heat setting of the stove.

Have to make one and see if it'll help. Reviews on Amazon indicate this device works.

Comment: Some tips, after experimenting with a DIY milk watcher made out of a small plate. 1) Make sure the plate has some uneven edges and holes to allow steam to escape. (2) Put a weight on the lid, like a heavy spoon to keep the plate horizontal. (3) Keep the heat source on low flame / temp; low enough that it does not overpower the ability of the punctured foam to allow steam to escape without the milk overflowing. This device works, but you need patience to find the right combination of plate size, heat intensity and vessel size. Happy experimenting!